# Remove part of the VBA code before saving

Tags: vba, excel

I use two macros in my workbook as there are some data manipulation required in between macros.

I can run Macro 1 and save the file as a *.xlsm and after data manipulation, need to run Macro 2.

I want to know the possibility of Remove Macro 1 before saving?

Answer (score 1):

Probably easiest way is to store the macro in a separate module, and this code removes the entire module:

```
Sub DeleteModule()
    Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject
    Dim VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent

    Set VBProj = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject
    Set VBComp = VBProj.VBComponents("Module1")
    VBProj.VBComponents.Remove VBComp
End Sub
```

This code is from  www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx , where you can find other useful information too.